# Unable to access file in HDFS through PySpark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, pyspark, hdfs

I am new to Spark and Hadoop. I'm trying to setup an EC2 cluster with Spark 2.0.

I copied a file to the ephemeral HDFS and can see it is there using
cd ../.

```
root@ip-172-31-58-53 bin]$ ./hadoop fs -ls /root/
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

Found 2 items
drwxr-xr-x   - root supergroup          0 2017-05-23 12:08 
/root/_distcp_logs_sls6bc
-rw-r--r--   3 root supergroup  543046714 2017-05-23 12:08 
/root/input.csv
```

Here's the python code I am submitting:

```
import sys

import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName("MatrixMult")\
        .getOrCreate()

    df = spark.read.option("header","true").csv("hdfs://ec2-54-144-193-191.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9000/root/input.csv")

    df.show(10)

    spark.close()
```

My hadoop core-site.xml has the following set:

```
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://ec2-54-144-193-191.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9000</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
  <value>hdfs://ec2-54-144-193-191.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9000</value>
</property>
```

Here's the error I get when I submit the job:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/python_code/matrix_mult.py", line 12, in <module>
    df = spark.read.option("header","true").csv("hdfs://ec2-54-144-193-191.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9000/root/input.csv")
  File "/root/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 380, in csv
  File "/root/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/root/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/root/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o32.csv.
: java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe; Host Details : local host is: "ip-172-31-58-53.ec2.internal/172.31.58.53"; destination host is: "ec2-54-144-193-191.compute-1.amazonaws.com":9000; 
...
```

Any idea why this may be happening? Any tips on how to debug it? I have tried using the internal name but that doesn't work either. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/python` at the top?

Answer (score 0):

I think you only configure either fs.defaultFS or fs.default.name: my core-site.xml as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!--
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://master:8020</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason was pretty silly. I was using the pre-compiled binaries downloaded from Apache. It expects you to have Hadoop 2. When you run the EC2 scripts, you must pass the flag --hadoop-major-version=2. I hadn't done that.

I rebuilt the cluster with this flag and it fixed the problem.